# How should I understand 今よりもっと?

Tags: words, phrases, spoken-language

> person: うん痩せたいです今よりもっと
>
> me: 私も... ;;
>
> person: だよなー
>
> person: I want to lose weight, now more than ever/especially now
>
> me: Me too... ;;
>
> person: Ya know-;)

Ok so だよなー is not an easy one to translate colloquially, but my question is about 今よりもっと.

How are my translations above, and how is this parsing?

> 今よりもっと
>
> now/more/more

or

> now/even more

Is this the より that means "more," as in the following example?

> よりいい物が見つからないので、今ある物で我慢しよう。 Since we can't find a better one, let's make the best of what we have.

Would anyone care to explain fully if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: The より in ヘレンより is "than", no? （よ↗り[LH]="more", より[HL・LL]="than"/"from"）because it can be replaced by よりも.

Comment: （あっ、でも、なくなってるぅ～）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often the case that some part, which a speaker thinks of while speaking is added to the end of a sentence, or even added as a new sentence.

In this case

> 今よりもっと痩せたいです → 痩せたいです今よりもっと

Of course, the first sentence just means

> I want to lose even more weight than now.

and the second sentence is just a rearranged version of the first.

Comment: does this より mean "more" or "than"?

Comment: 今 より もっと = now than more (i.e. more than now)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it just means 'more than is the case at the moment' - literally 'more than now' (it's the same より that you'd use for any comparison). So for your first example, the first speaker is saying 'I want to get thinner than [I am] right now'.